# Add new field with value from existing one in mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to add new fields to my existing collection. The collection look like this.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62df66945e2ecab37dd56a69"
  },
  "AllApplicableSteps": [
    {
      "StepName": "Open",
      "StepNo": 1,
      "StepDesc": "Open Step"
    },
    {
      "StepName": "Pending",
      "StepNo": 1,
      "StepDesc": "Pending Step"
    },
    {
      "StepName": "Approved",
      "StepNo": 3,
      "StepDesc": "successful"
    },
    {
      "StepName": "Rejected",
      "StepNo": 3,
      "StepDesc": "rejected"
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to add another field name like "StepTitle" which value will be the same as " StepName"

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62df66945e2ecab37dd56a69"
  },
  "AllApplicableSteps": [
    {
      "StepName": "Open",
      "StepTitle": "Open",
      "StepNo": 1,
      "StepDesc": "Open Step"
    },
    {
      "StepName": "Pending",
      "StepTitle": "Pending",
      "StepNo": 1,
      "StepDesc": "Pending Step"
    },
    {
      "StepName": "Approved",
      "StepTitle": "Approved",
      "StepNo": 3,
      "StepDesc": "successful"
    },
    {
      "StepName": "Rejected",
      "StepTitle": "Rejected",
      "StepNo": 3,
      "StepDesc": "rejected"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the aggregation pipeline I am trying with $set

```
{
  "AllApplicableSteps.StepTitle" : "$AllApplicableSteps.StepName"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K2Hj.png)

But above pipeline return an array of all stepName. EG.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDrrZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using `$map` to iterate over the array and transform each object independently, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      AllApplicableSteps: {
        $map: {
          input: "$AllApplicableSteps",
          in: {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                StepTitle: "$$this.StepName"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/18wa188S7fc)